Yocto recipes’ native and target dependencies nanbield
I’m quite new to Yocto. I'm using two versions of Yocto produced by nxp for 5.15 kernel(Kirkstone) and 6.6 kernel(Nanbield). And it is work with difference. I have a recipe of librttopo
SUMMARY = "RT Topology Library"
DESCRIPTION = "RT Topology library for Relief service"
HOMEPAGE = "https://github.com/CGX-GROUP/librttopo"
SECTION = "master"

LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "git://github.com/CGX-GROUP/librttopo.git;protocol=https;branch=master"
SRCREV = "ffcdc7ee67375c5874b09101dca3fc9fc98ecc08"

inherit autotools pkgconfig

DEPENDS = "geos geos-native"

S = "${WORKDIR}/git"

INSANE_SKIP += "configure-unsafe"

Recipe successfully builds in Kirkstone, but can't configure in Nanbield. I think problem is in usage geos geos-native together.
When i try to use only native it can't find .so library, when target it can't find config header. So config header and .so are presented in both recipe-sysroot and recipe-sysroot-native directories. What i'm doing wrong?
Log of build:
ERROR: librttopo-1.1.0-r0 do_configure: configure failed
ERROR: librttopo-1.1.0-r0 do_configure: ExecutionError('/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/temp/run.do_configure.3085577', 1, None, None)
ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in: /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/temp/log.do_configure.3085577
Log data follows:
| DEBUG: Executing python function extend_recipe_sysroot
| NOTE: Direct dependencies are ['/home/ruslan/embedded/custom-layers/meta-btp/recipes-jslibs/geos/geos_3.12.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-core/glibc/glibc_2.39.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-cross_13.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/gcc/gcc-runtime_13.2.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/libtool/libtool-cross_2.4.7.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/libtool/libtool-native_2.4.7.bb:do_populate_sysroot', '/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/quilt/quilt-native_0.67.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/ruslan/embedded/custom-layers/meta-btp/recipes-jslibs/geos/geos_3.12.1.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/autoconf/autoconf_2.72e.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/automake/automake_1.16.5.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/patch/patch_2.7.6.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pkgconfig/pkgconfig_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot', 'virtual:native:/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/recipes-devtools/pseudo/pseudo_git.bb:do_populate_sysroot']
| NOTE: Installed into sysroot: []
| NOTE: Skipping as already exists in sysroot: ['geos', 'gettext-minimal-native', 'glibc', 'binutils-cross-aarch64', 'cmake-native', 'gcc-cross-aarch64', 'gcc-runtime', 'libgcc', 'libtool-cross', 'libtool-native', 'm4-native', 'quilt-native', 'texinfo-dummy-native', 'linux-libc-headers', 'geos-native', 'openssl-native', 'ncurses-native', 'zlib-native', 'autoconf-native', 'automake-native', 'flex-native', 'gnu-config-native', 'make-native', 'patch-native', 'perl-native', 'pkgconfig-native', 'pseudo-native', 'bzip2-native', 'xz-native', 'zstd-native', 'attr-native', 'gdbm-native', 'gmp-native', 'libmpc-native', 'mpfr-native', 'sqlite3-native']
| DEBUG: Python function extend_recipe_sysroot finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function autotools_preconfigure
| DEBUG: Shell function autotools_preconfigure finished
| DEBUG: Executing python function autotools_aclocals
| DEBUG: SITE files ['endian-little', 'bit-64', 'arm-common', 'arm-64', 'common-linux', 'common-glibc', 'aarch64-linux', 'common']
| DEBUG: Python function autotools_aclocals finished
| DEBUG: Executing shell function do_configure
| automake (GNU automake) 1.16.5
| Copyright (C) 2021 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
| License GPLv2+: GNU GPL version 2 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html>
| This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
| There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
| 
| Written by Tom Tromey <tromey@redhat.com>
|        and Alexandre Duret-Lutz <adl@gnu.org>.
| AUTOV is 1.16
| NOTE: Executing ACLOCAL="aclocal --system-acdir=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/ --automake-acdir=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal-1.16" autoreconf -Wcross --verbose --install --force --exclude=autopoint -I /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/
| autoreconf: export WARNINGS=cross,no-obsolete
| autoreconf: Entering directory '.'
| autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
| autoreconf: running: aclocal --system-acdir=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/ --automake-acdir=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal-1.16 -I /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force -I m4
| autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
| autoreconf: running: libtoolize --copy --force
| libtoolize: putting auxiliary files in '.'.
| libtoolize: copying file './ltmain.sh'
| libtoolize: putting macros in AC_CONFIG_MACRO_DIRS, 'm4'.
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/libtool.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltoptions.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltsugar.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/ltversion.m4'
| libtoolize: copying file 'm4/lt~obsolete.m4'
| autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Intltool
| autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gtkdoc
| autoreconf: running: aclocal --system-acdir=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot/usr/share/aclocal/ --automake-acdir=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal-1.16 -I /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force -I m4
| autoreconf: running: /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/autoconf --include=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force
| autoreconf: running: /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/autoheader --include=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/share/aclocal/ --force
| autoreconf: running: automake --add-missing --copy --force-missing
| configure.ac:42: installing './compile'
| configure.ac:62: installing './config.guess'
| configure.ac:62: installing './config.sub'
| configure.ac:9: installing './install-sh'
| configure.ac:9: installing './missing'
| src/Makefile.am: installing './depcomp'
| autoreconf: './install-sh' is updated
| autoreconf: './config.sub' is updated
| autoreconf: './config.guess' is updated
| autoreconf: Leaving directory '.'
| NOTE: Running ../git/configure  --build=x86_64-linux            --host=aarch64-poky-linux               --target=aarch64-poky-linux             --prefix=/usr                   --exec_prefix=/usr                 --bindir=/usr/bin               --sbindir=/usr/sbin             --libexecdir=/usr/libexec               --datadir=/usr/share            --sysconfdir=/etc         --sharedstatedir=/com            --localstatedir=/var            --libdir=/usr/lib               --includedir=/usr/include               --oldincludedir=/usr/include            --infodir=/usr/share/info                  --mandir=/usr/share/man                 --disable-silent-rules                  --disable-dependency-tracking                   --with-libtool-sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot  --disable-static
| configure: loading site script /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/site/endian-little
| configure: loading site script /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/site/arm-common
| configure: loading site script /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/site/arm-64
| configure: loading site script /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/site/common-linux
| configure: loading site script /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/site/common-glibc
| configure: loading site script /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/sources/poky/meta/site/common
| checking for a BSD-compatible install... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/hosttools/install -c
| checking whether build environment is sane... yes
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-strip... aarch64-poky-linux-strip
| checking for a race-free mkdir -p... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/hosttools/mkdir -p
| checking for gawk... gawk
| checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
| checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
| checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
| checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-gcc... aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot
| checking whether the C compiler works... yes
| checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
| checking for suffix of executables...
| checking whether we are cross compiling... yes
| checking for suffix of object files... o
| checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... yes
| checking whether aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot accepts -g... yes
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot option to enable C11 features... none needed
| checking whether aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot understands -c and -o together... yes
| checking dependency style of aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot... none
| checking for stdio.h... yes
| checking for stdlib.h... yes
| checking for string.h... yes
| checking for inttypes.h... yes
| checking for stdint.h... yes
| checking for strings.h... yes
| checking for sys/stat.h... yes
| checking for sys/types.h... yes
| checking for unistd.h... yes
| checking for sys/time.h... yes
| checking for stdlib.h... (cached) yes
| checking for stdio.h... (cached) yes
| checking for string.h... (cached) yes
| checking for math.h... yes
| checking for float.h... yes
| checking for inttypes.h... (cached) yes
| checking for stdint.h... (cached) yes
| checking for ctype.h... yes
| checking for errno.h... yes
| checking for assert.h... yes
| checking for stdarg.h... yes
| checking whether the compiler supports GNU C++... yes
| checking whether aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot accepts -g... yes
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot option to enable C++11 features... none needed
| checking dependency style of aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot... none
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-gcc... (cached) aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot
| checking whether the compiler supports GNU C... (cached) yes
| checking whether aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot accepts -g... (cached) yes
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot option to enable C11 features... (cached) none needed
| checking whether aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot understands -c and -o together... (cached) yes
| checking dependency style of aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot... (cached) none
| checking how to run the C preprocessor... aarch64-poky-linux-gcc -E --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security
| checking whether ln -s works... yes
| checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... (cached) yes
| checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
| checking host system type... aarch64-poky-linux-gnu
| checking how to print strings... printf
| checking for a sed that does not truncate output... (cached) sed
| checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/hosttools/grep
| checking for egrep... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/hosttools/grep -E
| checking for fgrep... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/hosttools/grep -F
| checking for ld used by aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot... aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot
| checking if the linker (aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot ) is GNU ld... yes
| checking for BSD- or MS-compatible name lister (nm)... aarch64-poky-linux-gcc-nm
| checking the name lister (aarch64-poky-linux-gcc-nm) interface... BSD nm
| checking the maximum length of command line arguments... 1572864
| checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to aarch64-poky-linux-gnu format... func_convert_file_noop
| checking how to convert x86_64-pc-linux-gnu file names to toolchain format... func_convert_file_noop
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot  option to reload object files... -r
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-file... no
| checking for file... file
| configure: WARNING: using cross tools not prefixed with host triplet
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-objdump... aarch64-poky-linux-objdump
| checking how to recognize dependent libraries... pass_all
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-dlltool... dlltool
| checking how to associate runtime and link libraries... printf %s\n
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-ar... aarch64-poky-linux-gcc-ar
| checking for archiver @FILE support... @
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-strip... (cached) aarch64-poky-linux-strip
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-ranlib... aarch64-poky-linux-gcc-ranlib
| checking command to parse aarch64-poky-linux-gcc-nm output from aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot object... ok
| checking for sysroot... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot
| checking for a working dd... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/hosttools/dd
| checking how to truncate binary pipes... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/hosttools/dd bs=4096 count=1
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-mt... no
| checking for mt... no
| checking if : is a manifest tool... no
| checking for dlfcn.h... yes
| checking for objdir... .libs
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot supports -fno-rtti -fno-exceptions... no
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot static flag -static works... yes
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot supports -c -o file.o... yes
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
| checking whether the aarch64-poky-linux-gcc  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot linker (aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot ) supports shared libraries... yes
| checking whether -lc should be explicitly linked in... no
| checking dynamic linker characteristics... GNU/Linux ld.so
| checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
| checking whether stripping libraries is possible... yes
| checking if libtool supports shared libraries... yes
| checking whether to build shared libraries... yes
| checking whether to build static libraries... no
| checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot -E
| checking for ld used by aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot... aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot
| checking if the linker (aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot ) is GNU ld... yes
| checking whether the aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot linker (aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot ) supports shared libraries... yes
| checking for aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot option to produce PIC... -fPIC -DPIC
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot PIC flag -fPIC -DPIC works... yes
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot static flag -static works... yes
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot supports -c -o file.o... yes
| checking if aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot supports -c -o file.o... (cached) yes
| checking whether the aarch64-poky-linux-g++  -march=armv8-a+crc+crypto -mbranch-protection=standard -fstack-protector-strong  -O2 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -Wformat -Wformat-security -Werror=format-security --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot linker (aarch64-poky-linux-ld --sysroot=/home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot ) supports shared libraries... yes
| checking dynamic linker characteristics... (cached) GNU/Linux ld.so
| checking how to hardcode library paths into programs... immediate
| checking for an ANSI C-conforming const... yes
| checking for off_t... yes
| checking for size_t... yes
| checking whether struct tm is in sys/time.h or time.h... time.h
| checking for working volatile... yes
| checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... (cached) yes
| checking whether lstat accepts an empty string... (cached) no
| checking whether lstat correctly handles trailing slash... (cached) yes
| checking for working memcmp... (cached) yes
| checking whether stat accepts an empty string... (cached) no
| checking for strftime... yes
| checking for memset... yes
| checking for sqrt... no
| checking for strcasecmp... yes
| checking for strerror... (cached) yes
| checking for strncasecmp... yes
| checking for strstr... yes
| checking for fdatasync... yes
| checking for ftruncate... yes
| checking for getcwd... yes
| checking for gettimeofday... yes
| checking for localtime_r... yes
| checking for memmove... yes
| checking for strerror... (cached) yes
| checking for geos-config... /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/recipe-sysroot/usr/bin/crossscripts/geos-config
| checking for geos_c.h... no
| configure: error: could not find geos_c.h - you may need to specify the directory of a geos-config file using --with-geosconfig
| NOTE: The following config.log files may provide further information.
| NOTE: /home/ruslan/embedded/imx-yocto-bsp/build-btp/tmp/work/armv8a-poky-linux/librttopo/1.1.0/build/config.log
| ERROR: configure failed
| WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command.
ERROR: Task (/home/ruslan/embedded/custom-layers/meta-btp/recipes-jslibs/librttopo/librttopo_1.1.0.bb:do_configure) failed with exit code '1'
NOTE: Tasks Summary: Attempted 1036 tasks of which 989 didn't need to be rerun and 1 failed.

Summary: 1 task failed:
  /home/ruslan/embedded/custom-layers/meta-btp/recipes-jslibs/librttopo/librttopo_1.1.0.bb:do_configure
Summary: There were 2 ERROR messages, returning a non-zero exit code.


If you can't configure or experience any issue, you should dump the error message.
